# Big-Oh Complexity T(n) = (log(n) +1)(log(n)+2)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand what would be the Big-Of for T(n).  Using the limit I know n would dominate this expression.

T(n) = (log(n)+2)*(log(n)+1))

Would T(n) = O(log(n))?

Comment: More like `log(n)^2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(log(n)+2)*(log(n)+1)
=> logn*logn + 3logn + 2 

--- drop constants ---

=> O(logn*logn + 3logn) = O((logn)^2)
```